# QA model return the best answers to the same question from multiple contexts

Tags: python, nlp-question-answering

I am trying to build a QA system using a pre-trained QA model.

I have a list of texts and I basically want to extract the 'best x' answers to the same question using each text:

example:

```
contexts = ['the car is red', 'the car is yellow' , 'I love cats' , 'my car is green', 'the airplane is white'  ....]
question = 'what color is the car?'
```

for far I can answer one text at the time:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering
import torch

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad")
qa_model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("bert-large-uncased-whole-

word-masking-finetuned-squad")
inputs = tokenizer(question, contexts[0], add_special_tokens=True, return_tensors="pt")
input_ids = inputs["input_ids"].tolist()[0]

outputs = qa_model(**inputs)

answer_start_scores = outputs.start_logits
answer_end_scores = outputs.end_logits

answer_start= torch.argmax(answer_start_scores)
answer_end = torch.argmax(answer_end_scores) +1

answer = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_string(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids[answer_start:answer_end]))
answer
```

I could then apply a for loop on each text and extract all the answers

but: 1) i am not sure it would be the most efficient way to go through each context 2) I cannot rank the answers from the best to the worst answer (i.e. the answer which is most likely to be answering the question and the answer which is less likely to be a plausible answer to the question)

how can I efficiently go through each context to  find an answers and rank the answers from the most coherent with the question to the least coherent?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to join context to one string, and treat each of them as separate sentence.
Then get N best results from QA model, see the scores and check in which contexts given answer appeared:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering
import torch
import numpy as np

contexts = ['the car is red', 'the car is yellow' , 'I love cats' , 'my car is green', 'the airplane is white' ]
question = 'what color is the car?'

#combine context and create list of indexes where in joined context next context starts
context = ('. ').join(contexts) + '.'
context_bins = np.cumsum([len(c)+1 for c in contexts])

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad")
qa_model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad")

inputs = tokenizer(question, context, add_special_tokens=True, return_tensors="pt")
input_ids = inputs["input_ids"].tolist()[0]

outputs = qa_model(**inputs)

# convert scores to probabilities 
answer_start_scores = torch.nn.functional.softmax(outputs.start_logits)
answer_end_scores = torch.nn.functional.softmax(outputs.end_logits)
# or you can use logits
# answer_start_scores = outputs.start_logits
# answer_end_scores = outputs.end_logits

# Extract 5 greatest values fo start and end scores with indeces
answer_start_scores, answers_starts_idx = torch.topk(answer_start_scores, k=5)
answer_end_scores, answers_ends_idx = torch.topk(answer_end_scores, k=5)

print(f'Q: {question}')

for si, ei, ss, es in zip(
    answers_starts_idx[0], 
    answers_ends_idx[0],
    answer_start_scores[0],
    answer_end_scores[0]):

    score = ss*es

    context_idx = [i for i,p in enumerate(context_bins) if p > si][0]
    matching_context = contexts[ context_idx ]

    answer = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_string(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids[si:ei+1]))
    print(f'Score: {score:<7.7f} A: {answer:<30}; In context {context_idx} : {matching_context}')
```

output:

```
Q: what color is the car?
Score: 0.8851697 A: red                           ; In context 0 : the car is red
Score: 0.0014527 A: yellow                        ; In context 1 : the car is yellow
Score: 0.0000762 A: the car is red.               ; In context 0 : the car is red
Score: 0.0000069 A: green                         ; In context 1 : the car is yellow
Score: 0.0000011 A: car is red. the car is yellow.; In context 0 : the car is red
```